# Why am I getting two processes when I add something to my .bashrc

Tags: raspbian, bash

I am hacking around with a component on a board that needs networking. To accomplish that I open a terminal at startup and I added a startup.sh script to the bottom of my ~/.bashrc. However, when I restart and then run a process check I notice 2 instances.

```
pi         841   826  0 07:17 tty1     00:00:00 /bin/bash --rcfile ./bin/startup.sh
pi         998   985  0 07:17 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash --rcfile ./bin/startup.sh
```

Now if I remove the line from .bashrc and then add after startup and open a terminal I only get 1 instance. I disable the line in the bashrc before opening the other terminal to run `ps` so it shouldn't be that either (also seems to be confirmed by PID)

Why is this happening? Can I make it so only 1 is starting?

Comment: Using `.bashrc` to do anything other than configure the shell/environment is a bad practice that for whatever reason is virulent among pi users -- likely due lousy blogs spreading it like a virus.

Comment: Good point I was incorrectly assuming that .bash_profile ran before networking was set up. However, I switched it around and it still seems to work. So if I move it there it does seem to work better,

Comment: You've been misled. Exploiting the autologin commonly used with the pi makes it *seem* like `.profile` or `.bashrc` are scripts executed by the system at boot. **They aren't** -- they are executed on a per user basis whenever a new shell is started, depending on context. If you are using the system interactively (i.e. via a keyboard, etc.), or logging in remotely, this could happen *many* times, and not only at boot. See **INVOCATION** in `man bash`. You've gotten around part of the issue by using `--rcfile` so that that file won't normally be used.

Comment: So where would you suggest? Although I understand those concerns no one *should* be logging into the box. Do I need to dig into something more basic in the os?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re looking to launch some program on boot, you should use a systemd script.

You can create the file `/etc/systemd/system/component.service` with the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=component
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/start.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You mentioned your component requires networking, which is what the `Wants=` and `After=` lines guarantee.

Once you have the file in place you need to reload systemd with the command `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

To get it to automatically start on boot, run `sudo systemctl enable component.service`

There are a number of commands you can run against the service with the format  `sudo systemctl <command> component.service`:

- `disable` - stop the service from automatically starting on boot
- `start` - start the service now
- `stop` - stop the service now
- `restart` - restart the service
- `status` - see the current status of the service

You can also get a log of the programs output with the command `journalctl -u component.service`

Be mindful that if your startup script exits (based on your question it doesn't seem to, but perhaps it does), you may need to use a "oneshot" service setup rather than the one listed above.  Take a look at this existing SO post for the difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39032100/what-is-the-difference-between-systemd-service-type-oneshot-and-simple

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

So after reading about the difference between TTY and PTY I realised I could just stop starting the terminal at startup and an emulated terminal in the background will still call .bashrc. So my solution was to remove `@lxterminal` from `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`